# PyGame: Stop moving a polygon once a stop message is received from Socket

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

I have a python script for PyGame which moves a polygon over the screen. It shall stop moving the polygon once it receives the message "Stop" via the socket. Currently the whole pyGame Script is ended when it receives the stop message. I want that the current position of the polygon is still displayed.

This is the code for the moving polygon:

```
import pygame
import select
import socket

# Initialize pygame and create a window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

# Set up the socket connection
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('192.168.178.49', 5000))
server_socket.listen(1)

# Set up the triangle
triangle_pos = [0, 10]
triangle_speed = 1

# Initialize the stop_movement variable
stop_movement = False

# Start the main loop
exiting = False
while not exiting:
    # Check for any incoming messages from the socket connection
    inputs, _, _ = select.select([server_socket], [], [], 0.1)
    for sock in inputs:
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if data == b'stop':
            stop_movement = True
        else:
            stop_movement = False

    # Update the triangle position if it has not been stopped
    if not stop_movement:
        triangle_pos[0] += triangle_speed
        if triangle_pos[0] > 640:
            triangle_pos[0] = 0

    # Draw the triangle
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255, 0, 0), [(triangle_pos[0], triangle_pos[1]), (triangle_pos[0]+5, triangle_pos[1]+10), (triangle_pos[0]-5, triangle_pos[1]+10)])

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Check for quit event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exiting = True

# Quit Pygame
pygame.quit()
```

And this is the code for the sender on the other side of the socket:

```
import socket

# Set up the socket connection
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('192.168.178.49', 5000))

# Send the "stop" message
client_socket.send(b'stop')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are exiting the loop and quitting Pygame when it receives the "stop" message through socket. you need to modify the code to keep on showing the current position of the polygon even if the "stop" message is received.

Comment: @Michael That's certainly not what happens here. The problem is calling `recv` on the socket directly instead of the connection returned by calling `accept`.

Answer (score 2):

When `select.select` returns an input socket, you should call `accept` on that socket and then use the returned connection object to receive the data.

Also, the socket should be non-blocking, so the game loop can run while checking for data on that connection.

Here's a quick'n'dirty example:

*part 1:*

```
import pygame
import select
import socket

# Initialize pygame and create a window
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))

# Set up the socket connection
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 5000))
server_socket.listen(1)
server_socket.setblocking(False) # <========= the socket should not block

# Set up the triangle
triangle_pos = [0, 10]
triangle_speed = 5

# Initialize the stop_movement variable
stop_movement = False

# Start the main loop
exiting = False
connection = None
while not exiting:
    # Check for any incoming messages from the socket connection
    inputs, _, _ = select.select([server_socket], [], [], 0.1)
    for sock in inputs:
        connection, addr = sock.accept() # <========= keep track of the connection
        print('Connected')
        
    if connection:
        try:
            data = connection.recv(1024) # <========= call recv on the connection
            print(data)
            if data == b'stop':
                stop_movement = True
            else:
                stop_movement = False
        except: # <========= if there's no data, ignore it
            pass

    # Update the triangle position if it has not been stopped
    if not stop_movement:
        triangle_pos[0] += triangle_speed
        if triangle_pos[0] > 640:
            triangle_pos[0] = 0

    screen.fill('black') # <========= clear the screen 
    # Draw the triangle
    pygame.draw.polygon(screen, (255, 0, 0), [(triangle_pos[0], triangle_pos[1]), (triangle_pos[0]+5, triangle_pos[1]+10), (triangle_pos[0]-5, triangle_pos[1]+10)])

    # Update the display
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Check for quit event
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exiting = True

# Quit Pygame
pygame.quit()
```

*part 2:*

```
import socket, time

# Set up the socket connection
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5000))

# Send the "stop" message
while True:
    client_socket.send(b'stop')
    time.sleep(1)
    client_socket.send(b'start')
    time.sleep(2)
```